# C# - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, exception, null

I'm currently trying to check if a reference is null before it is used by 'MyMethod' with:

```
if (School.ClassRoom.Pupil.Age != null)
        {
            MyMethod(School.ClassRoom.Pupil.Age);
        }
```

However, I'm still getting the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the first line because not only is the Age null, but also the Pupil and ClassRoom are sometimes null too.

I'm getting the same problems using Try, Catch, Finally, since I get the same error in the Try piece of code.

I don't want to have to check each ClassRoom for null, and then each Pupil for null, and then each Age for null each time I want to use this method.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: How do you fill School.ClassRoom.. data? While filling, dont allow NULL lines may be a solution?

Comment: Btw, your title doesnt seems appropriate. There is nothing confusing about the exception you are getting.

Comment: If possible I'd like to be able to continue using null classes since this is part of quite a complex data structure and if I start having new instances of all the nulls then I think the memory usage would go through the roof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: the answer below was written in 2010, long before the *null conditional* operator was introduced in C# 6.

---

It sounds like you're after something like Groovy's null-safe dereferencing operator, which would let you write `if (School?.ClassRoom?.Pupil?.Age != null)` - but C# didn't have such a thing before C# 6.

I'm afraid you *have* to check each property for nullity, assuming it can *be* null:

```
if (School != null && School.ClassRoom != null && School.ClassRoom.Pupil != null
    && School.ClassRoom.Pupil.Age != null)
{
    MyMethod(School.ClassRoom.Pupil.Age);
}
```

Of course, you could put this whole `if` block including the method call itself in a helper method, and just call that.

That's assuming it's valid for each property to *be* null to start with. If you are able to design your classes so that null values aren't even allowed - and you validate this in contsructors etc - your code is likely to end up being a lot cleaner.

It's worth noting that there are two alternative approaches here - the one put forward by Chris in another answer is to create a "default" object for each property; I *usually* find that it's better to always require a "real" value to be provided in a constructor. Default objects without real data can end up causing bugs which are harder to track down than `NullReferenceException` problems, as you can happily go along with the "dummy" data for a long time, and just get the wrong result at the end. There are definitely times where it *is* the right thing to do, however - particularly when it comes to collections. It depends on the situation.

EDIT: Saeed has suggested an extension method in the comments. I assume this would be something like:

```
public static int? PupilAgeOrNull(this School school)
{
    return school != null && 
           school.ClassRoom != null && 
           school.ClassRoom.Pupil != null
           ? school.ClassRoom.Pupil.Age : null;
}
```

(Adjust for types appropriately.)

I definitely prefer the idea of trying to keep things non-null elsewhere, but this will do it if you need it. It feels wrong to me though. At the heart of this gut feeling is the fact that you're navigating three or four properties to start with - this feels like a violation of the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) to me. Now I'm not one to get dogmatic about such things, but putting an extension method *on `School`* feels far too specific to me, for such a long path of properties.

Another alternative - which is also somewhat nasty, IMO - is to write three different extension methods:

```
public static ClassRoom ClassRoomOrNull(this School school)
{
    return school == null ? null : school.ClassRoom;
}

public static Pupil PupilOrNull(this ClassRoom classRoom)
{
    return classRoom == null ? null : classRoom.Pupil;
}

public static int? AgeOrNull(this Pupil pupil)
{
    return pupil == null ? null : pupil.Age;
}
```

Then you can write:

```
int? age = School.ClassRoomOrNull().PupilOrNull().AgeOrNull();
if (age != null)
{
    MyMethod(age);
}
```

This means that the extension method on `School` isn't nearly so specific. You've still got a long chain of method calls, and I'd still try to redesign to avoid this situation if possible, but at least there isn't quite such a tight tie from `School` to `School.ClassRoom.Pupil.Age`.

Comment: he wants do not do this, instead of `if` write an extension method

Comment: @Saeed: Um, where did he mention extension methods?

Comment: if (School.IsNullAge()) It's easy to write such a function, why should he mention this, he don't like ugly code

Comment: @Saeed: And what's the method going to look like? It'll have basically the same code in. I also doubt that it's the cleanest solution. Admittedly it does only mean writing the code once.

Comment: @Saeed: I've added your suggestion to my answer, but it feels wrong to me - I'm editing to explain why.

Comment: @Jon, I preferred `ClassRoomOrNull` ... but there are some issue, first for each property should add one method, second the chain is too long in some cases, I think the way suggested in @Jani's refered article is better but a little complicated than normal ways.

Comment: @Saeed: The expression tree solution is a little too magical - and brittle - for me. Anyway, I hope I've represented your suggestion fairly - as well as my reservations about it.

Comment: Yes, my base suggestion was like `ClassRoomOrNull` but i didn't like write it completely because I know you can understand why I suggest Extension method not regular methods, but I'm not going to remove downvote because your first answer was exactly the things questioner told he don't like do it.

Comment: +1 This is an incredibly comprehensive and patient explanation. This is a shining example of what makes this community awesome.

Comment: Thanks for exploring the options for me. At this stage I think the null values will have to be there, so I'm going to go with the original idea of checking each. I'm marking this as the answer though since the if statement you provided with the && functions in it is written more concisely than I had anticipated. I'll look into Law of Demeter and see if I can use it to improve my code.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/automating-null-checks-with-linq-expressions/) is a nice and elegant solution with **Expression Trees**.
Try it and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Give the code you have shown, there is not an easier way. You will need to check each component.

```
if (School != null && School.ClassRoom != null 
  && School.ClassRoom.Pupil != null 
  && School.ClassRoom.Pupil.Age != null) 
{
  ...
}
```

However, you can write your code in such a way that the members are never `null`. That way you can avoidn having to check for `null`. For example

```
class School
{
  private ClassRoom _classRoom = new ClassRoom();

  public ClassRoom ClassRoom 
  {
    get {return _classRoom;}
  }
}
```

This will give School an empty class room to start with, so it is not `null` and cannot be set to `null` outside of the class since the property does not have a setter. You can carry this concept forward, your list of pupils (I assume this would be a list) can be an empty list rather than a null instance etc.

Answer (score 1):

"Null-Object Pattern" comes to your rescue. Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

So, you can have NullSchool, NullClassRoom, NullPupil, NullAge.

Then you never need to check for null thing, instead you can have just one check (or method, like IsValid() in Age class, ofcourse virtual) in MyMethod to reject a age if it is not valid.

Comment: Well it *may* come to the rescue. It depends whether there really *is* a sensible "null" version. As I wrote in my answer, providing dummy data can easily lead to hard-to-diagnose problems.